# TPR TNR problem with logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, model, sensitivity-specificity

I have implemented a modified logistic regression with update equation of weights as

[image] 
where   $ h_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta^{T}x}} $, sigmoid function. $x^{(i)}$ being $i$ th data sample, $y^{i}$, $i$ th output. 
I learnt about this from an online course on Machine learning by Andrew N G. Accuracy was so low, near 50%. But one thing I observed was, TPR (True Positive Rate)(sensitivity) and TNR(True Negative Rate)(specificity) are always opposite to each other. Like negatively correlated. I have checked my code several times, whether it's because of computation error, but it isn't. Ideally, TPR (True Positive Rate)(sensitivity) and TNR (True Negative rate)(specificity) must not be dependent. 
Here's how they are: [image]
 I used 10 fold cross validation to generate 10 clsssifiers, 10 times. Overall 100 classifiers. X axis is the classifier number out of 100 classifiers found.

What this correlation actually says ? How to improve the model to remove this dependency. What's the main reason for this.

Comment: What is the x-axis in your graph?

Comment: sorry, it's Classifier index... TPR, TNR for each classifier found from cross validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a number of samples or choose different cut-offs then you would expect to get a negative relationship here. Suppose either the sample or the cut-off is set to make it easy to detect true cases resulting in a high sensitivity then that will be at the expense of including more true non-cases and so the specificity will suffer. Plotting the results as an ROC curve will probably show things quite clearly.